# Joomla - Displaying Submenu OF all pages ON all pages

Tags: html, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a problem using Joomla 2.5.

I'm displaying my navigation on a different way than usual. My mainMenu and subMenu are positioned separated from each other. (Required by the jQuery animation I've implemented)

There is a need to retain the menuStructure therefor i've created the following menu:
*(in this example I only give the first 2 mainMenuItems a subMenu)*

- mainMenuItem #1 {Alias of subMenuHead #1}
- mainMenuItem #2 {Alias of subMenuHead #2}
- mainMenuItem #3
- mainMenuItem #4

The Submenu's:
*in the settings, only the first level of Children are displayed!*

- subMenuHead #1
- - subMenuItem #1.1
- - subMenuItem #1.2

- subMenuHead #2
- - subMenuItem #2.1
- - subMenuItem #2.2

My Problem?
The subMenus are **only** being displayed if the user is on the Parent-page or the actual page it self. Even when set they should display on all pages.

So for example:
 When I navigate to mainMenuItem #3 I am unable to see any subMenus.
When I navigate to subMenuItem #1.2 I only see the subMenu of mainMenuItem #1.

When I navigate to subMenuItem #2.1 I only see the subMenu of mainMenuItem #2.

What I want:
All subMenus being displayed, on all pages *(Menu Assignment is set like so)*.

Don't understand? Maybe the direct link may help :) *(Dutch-text)*: http://www.notabilisweb.nl/tenc2012/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, i checked the pages and their sourcecode, but it seems that when it's not showed, the code of the submenu isn't even generated, so we can conclude that the jQuery code is fine, so this is the only cause i can imagine until now: In the module manager, are the menus assigned to all menus ?

Comment: I got it working, somehow/somewhat... The only downside: It only generates the menu when the "Start level"-setting is set to 1. Strange enough. When its set to 2, the entire menu disappears.
My jQuery is also doing things that it shouldn't. But that's another case for another question...

Comment: i checked your menu but it's somehow not stable, maybe you should try another JS/jQuery library, by the way you should checkout "swmenupro" component, there's also the "swmenufree" a free version with some limits. Anyway it's a good component wich produces menu modules and there's also menu(s) with some animation ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using the default Joomla menu module. In the module you are using to display the submenu, you should make sure that the "Show Sub-menu Items" setting is set to Yes.

Comment: That did a small part of the trick :). I thought that was set. Forgot it for 1 of the subMenus.
How come when I set the "Start-Level"-setting to 2 the menu completely disappears (except on the actual page it links to + its parents).

Comment: You're menu's are probably not that deep. When counting menu levels, the start level of the top level menus is 0.

Comment: Well 0 is not an option. When you set it to 1, it displays the "highest root". I've got a subMenu that only contains a Main with a child. When set to 2, the Menu disappears from all pages except for the one it links to.

Comment: Hmm. Apparently in 2.5 Joomla now uses 1 for the main menu level. I would need to see how your menus are configured because that module works if you don't make any mods. Any reason you are not using one of the many proven menu modules?